# MPMoviePlayerViewController in UIModalPresentationFormSheet reloads again

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am loading video with presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated in UIModalPresentationFormSheet. when i come beck from video by taping done view (UIModalPresentationFormSheet) animate again. how to disable that animation or disable reloading the view?